# SQl Server Converting to Date fails , DateTime works

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a `varchar(25)` column that holds a date value. A typical value is '11/04/2017'.

This query returns 0 rows

```
select * 
from myTable  
where isdate(inputDate) = 0
```

I am trying to find a max on this, using a date sort.

This query returns the expected result

```
;with gooddates as 
(
    select 
        medcomfolder, PatientId, PatientBirthday, InputDate 
    from 
        myTable 
    where 
        isdate(inputDate) = 1
)
select max(convert(datetime, inputDate)) 
from gooddates
```

This query returns an error.

```
;with gooddates as 
(
     select 
         medcomfolder, PatientId, PatientBirthday, InputDate 
     from 
         dwhFuData   
     where 
         isdate(inputdate) = 1
)
select max(convert(date, inputdate)) 
from gooddates
```

This is the returned error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 274
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The difference between the 2 queries is that the first is converting to a dateTime while the latter is converting to a date.

At this point, I can move forward w/ the dateTime option, but I am left wondering what I am missing.

I have checked that there are no embedded spaces, and all the columns have a  `len(InputDate) = 10`  (there is NO time data included)

I selected distinct values,put them in excel, and did a date function on each row. I was hoping to get a **#VALUE** on 1 row. All the rows worked.

So there is nothing silly like '02/31/2019' going on.

How can a dateTime conversion pass when a simple date conversion does not?

Comment: `select max(try_convert(date,inputDate)) from gooddates`

Comment: Check if there are extra characters or so in the field. If the format is 'mm/dd/yyyy' then there should not be more than 10 characters. Try using DATALENGTH, not LEN since that wont give you trailing spaces                                        
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATALENGTH(inputDate) > 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have values that include a time stamp following the date (based on the fact that `isdate()` is always zero).

If so, one simple solution would be to use `convert(date, left(inputdate, 10))`.  Another solution uses `try_convert()`:

```
try_convert(date, inputdate)
```

To find the offending values:

```
select inputdate
from dwhFuData
where try_convert(date, inputdate) is null and inputdate is not null;
```

Comment: '05/02/  18'  was the offending value.  In hindsight , i checked for leading and trailing  blanks.   Just a note to anyone following along... check your compatibility level if you get an Error that   TRY_CONVERT is not a built in function.   Has to be >=12